# CSS Grid Как продублировать блок?

Tags: css3, css-grid

[image: У меня есть блок, который я хочу продублировать.]

У меня есть грид таблица, в которой 6 столбцов. 
Я хочу 1 блок перенести в 6 блок. 
Когда я размечаю его в 6 колонку у меня схлопываться вся сетка.

Пример кода ниже:

```
.grid-container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 150px repeat(4, 2fr) 150px;
grid-template-rows: auto;
grid-template-areas: "number description description . . number"
                     "work work work work work work";
grid-row-gap: 20px;
```

}

Comment: Если нужно скинуть дополнительный код, скину.

Comment: Грид не умеет дублировать блоки, вам придётся копировать HTML (если я правильно понял ваш вопрос).

Comment: Да, я так и сделал.